# What extra fields does the AWS Amplify API include when invoking a Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

I have this AWS Lambda function to create a note object in my DynamoDB table:

```
import * as uuid from "uuid";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export function main(event, context, callback) {
  // Request body is passed in as a JSON encoded string in 'event.body'
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.tableName,
    // 'Item' contains the attributes of the item to be created
    // - 'userId': user identities are federated through the
    //             Cognito Identity Pool, we will use the identity id
    //             as the user id of the authenticated user
    // - 'noteId': a unique uuid
    // - 'content': parsed from request body
    // - 'attachment': parsed from request body
    // - 'createdAt': current Unix timestamp
    Item: {
      userId: event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId,
      noteId: uuid.v1(),
      content: data.content,
      attachment: data.attachment,
      createdAt: Date.now()
    }
  };

  dynamoDb.put(params, (error, data) => {
    // Set response headers to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)
    const headers = {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    };

    // Return status code 500 on error
    if (error) {
      const response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({ status: false })
      };
      callback(null, response);
      return;
    }

    // Return status code 200 and the newly created item
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(params.Item)
    };
    callback(null, response);
  });
}
```

What it does is not really relevant to the question. The important thing to note here is that it can be successfully executed offline with the command `serverless invoke local --function create --path mocks/create-event.json` and an example event `create-event.json`:

```
{
  "body": "{\"content\":\"hello world\",\"attachment\":\"hello.jpg\"}",
  "requestContext": {
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityId": "USER-SUB-1234"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I invoke this Lambda function with a POST request through the `aws-amplify` API, I only define a `body` field in the `init` object, i.e.

```
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
...
function createNote(note) {
  return API.post("scratch-notes", "/scratch-notes", {
    body: note
  });
}
```

Which leads to the following questions...

- How did the Lambda function get the needed `requestContext` field
  from the `aws-amplify` API POST method that invoked it?
- Was it appended to the `init` object by the `aws-amplify` API?

That would be the obvious answer, but that leads me to another question...

- What other fields are appended to the `init` object by the `aws-amplify` API?

Answer (score 0):

The `event` object also contains two extra structures, afaik: a `requestContext` object and a `pathParameters` object.

The `requestContext` object is just the `context` object included in the `event` object for testing purposes and for our general convenience.

The `pathParameters` object is a list of fields that are extracted from paths with special tokens.

```
  get:
    handler: get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: scratch-notes/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

A handler like that would take a request with the URI `scratch-notes/1234` and return a `pathParameters` object as follows:

```
{
  "pathParameters": {
    "id": "1234"
  }
}
```

Of course, both objects can be combined to invoke our API offline with the Serverless framework which would look like this:

```
{
  "pathParameters": {
    "id": "59747e00-8e61-11ea-8cb8-5d9bcedbe6f4"
  },
  "body": "myBody",
  "requestContext": {
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityId": "USER-SUB-1234"
    }
  }
}
```